# How to read interleaved binary data from a Raspberry Pi Camera v2

Tags: r, matrix, binary, raspberry-pi, raster

I am attempting to take unencoded images for a remote sensing project for vegetation mapping. My setup is a PiCamera v2 NoIR on a Raspberry Pi 3, with the included Roscolux #2007 StoraroBlue gel filter taped over the sensor and a SenseHat for environmental logging.

I can take normal PNG photos just fine, but I can't figure out how to read the binary data correctly, as all my attempts result in a striped mess of colors.

Here is the section of the Python script that captures the images:

```
def picamera_logging_thread():
    logger.info('Started camera logging thread')
    while time() < start_time + timeout:
        with PiCamera() as camera:
            # set values
            camera.resolution = (3280, 2464)

            # let automatic exposure settle
            sleep(2)
            image_name = 'image_' + str(int(time()))

            # capture in PNG format at native resolution
            camera.capture(os.path.join(image_dir, image_name + '.png'))
            logger.info('Saved image ' + image_name + '.png')

            # let automatic exposure settle
            sleep(2)
            image_name = 'image_' + str(int(time()))

            # capture in unencoded RGB format
            camera.capture(os.path.join(image_dir, image_name + '.bip'), 'rgb')
            logger.info('Saved image ' + image_name + '.bip')

        # delay the specified interval
        sleep(picamera_logging_interval - 4)
    logger.info('Stopped camera logging thread')

start_time = time()

# start logging threads
Thread(target = sensehat_logging_thread).start()
Thread(target = picamera_logging_thread).start()
```

The online documentation for capturing unencoded RGB images using the picamera Python library says this:

> The resulting RGB data is interleaved. That is to say that the red, green and blue values for a given pixel are grouped together, in that order. The first byte of the data is the red value for the pixel at (0, 0), the second byte is the green value for the same pixel, and the third byte is the blue value for that pixel. The fourth byte is the red value for the pixel at (1, 0), and so on.

Now, I gather that means the resulting binary data will be in standard BIP (Band Interleaved by Pixel) format, but I'm unsure whether their wording infers the pixels are grouped into rows or columns, because they say the second pixel is at (1, 0), which makes me think the second pixel in the data is at Row 2, Column 1 instead of the expected Column 2, Row 1.

I wrote a script in R that reads the data as a matrix of 1 byte integers (0 - 255) and adds them to a RasterStack of three RasterLayer objects, one for each band (RGB). I even tried adding an `.hdr` file and opening it in QGIS, but it's always striped noise.

Here is the R script:

```
# This script parses BIP pixel data from a binary file, assuming order band first then rowwise

# imports
#install.packages("raster")
library(raster)

# define filename of binary data
binary_filename <- "image_1490191326.bip"

# define pixel dimensions of the data, width then height
pixel_dimensions <- c(width = 3280, height = 2464)

# open file connection in Binary Read mode
data_file <- file(binary_filename, "rb")

# get data (and upshift)
binary_data <-
  readBin(
    data_file,
    what = "int",
    size = 1,
    n = pixel_dimensions["height"] * pixel_dimensions["width"] * 3 # hopefully the number of bytes in the file
  ) + 128 # upshift data from (-128, 127) to (0, 255) by adding 128

# close connection to file
close(data_file)

# create red raster layer of every 3rd byte, starting at the first one
red <-
  raster(
    matrix(binary_data[seq(from = 1,
                           to = length(binary_data),
                           by = 3)], nrow = pixel_dimensions["width"], ncol = pixel_dimensions["height"]),
    ymn = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2 * -1,
    ymx = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2,
    xmn = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2 * -1,
    xmx = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2
  )
names(red) <- "red"

# create green raster layer of every 3rd byte, starting at the second one
green <-
  raster(
    matrix(binary_data[seq(from = 2,
                           to = length(binary_data),
                           by = 3)], nrow = pixel_dimensions["width"], ncol = pixel_dimensions["height"]),
    ymn = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2 * -1,
    ymx = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2,
    xmn = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2 * -1,
    xmx = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2
  )
names(green) <- "green"

# create blue raster layer of every 3rd byte, starting at the third one
blue <-
  raster(
    matrix(binary_data[seq(from = 3,
                           to = length(binary_data),
                           by = 3)], nrow = pixel_dimensions["width"], ncol = pixel_dimensions["height"]),
    ymn = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2 * -1,
    ymx = pixel_dimensions["height"] / 2,
    xmn = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2 * -1,
    xmx = pixel_dimensions["width"] / 2
  )
names(blue) <- "blue"

# create raster stack of the three layers
rgb_stack <- stack(red, green, blue)

# plot hopefully correct raster
plot(rgb_stack)
plotRGB(rgb_stack)

# remove unused large data variables from memory
rm(red, green, blue, binary_data)
```

[Here is a link to a Google Drive folder with the binary data, R output, and a JPG version of the PNG image.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwM08rlWhwyPWkU5SkgwS3NjbzQ)

What am I doing wrong here? How might I read this and extract useable pixel data?

Comment: Can you share an image please?

Comment: sure thing, edited to add images

Comment: Sorry, I mean the raw BIP image.

Comment: Since I just created this account to ask this question, I can only post two links right now, so I posted a link to the binary data and to what the picture should look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! I think I have solved it. The image is actually padded with some unused pixels on the right and bottom edges (which you can see as black in the image below), so the publicised dimensions of `3280x2464` are incorrect in the case of a raw image. The correct ones are `3296x2464` and if you multiply these numbers together and then multiply by 3 (for R,G & B pixels), you will get a file size that matches yours.

You can convert the `RGB` file to a `JPEG` with **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS/OSX and Windows (and Raspberry Pi):

```
magick -depth 8 -size 3296x2464 image.rgb result.jpg
```

[image]

**Note 1**: If your filename doesn't actually end in `.rgb`, you can instead prefix it with `RGB:` to give ImageMagick a hint as to its contents, e.g.

```
magick -depth ... -size ... RGB:image.xyz ...
```

**Note 2**: If you use an older version of ImageMagick, replace `magick` with `convert`.

**Note 3**: If you want to crop off the black padding pixels with ImageMagick, use:

```
convert -depth 8 -size 3296x2464 image.rgb -trim result.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this, I never thought to look at file size. Assuming a 4:3 aspect ratio of the sensor at full resolution (from the documentation), and since Windows tells me the file has a size of 24,364,032 bytes (24,367,104 on disk), I think the dimensions should be around 3290x2467 from the algebra, but ImageMagick gives an error `magick.exe: unexpected end-of-file 'image_1490191326.rgb': No such file or directory @ error/rgb.c/ReadRGBImage/238.`

Thank you again for pointing me in a new direction! I have been stuck on this for a while.

Comment: Please try again - I have modified one of the numbers slightly to get rid of the error message.

Comment: IT WORKED!!! Thank you so much!

`magick.exe -depth 8 -size 3296x2464 image_1490191326.rgb result.tiff` worked perfectly